# Question about the proof of Theorem 2.19 (Page 38) of the book Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

At the last line of [the proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA38):

$\lambda^{-1}(n)=\mu(n)\lambda(n)=\mu^2(n)=|\mu(n)|$.

Why $\mu(n)\lambda(n)=\mu^2(n)$? How to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is not squarefree, both sides are zero.

If $n$ is squarefree, then $\mu(n)=\lambda(n)$.